# Why does the <router-outlet> component not cover 100% of the available height?

Tags: angular

I have 3 components:

```
<menu (setAnimal)='setAnimal($event)' ></menu>
 //principalComponent
<router-outlet (activate)='onActivate($event)'></router-outlet>
<footer></footer>
```

The red border component is called the `PrincipalComponent` and this should have the available height that results from removing the space occupied by the header and the footer. How can I make the `PrincipalComponent` encompass the total height of the available space?

[image]

this is my code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h5odfy?file=app/principal.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'principal',
      template: '<div style="height:100%;border:1px solid red;"> <h1>animal selected: {{animal}}</h1></div>',
      styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
    })
    export class PrincipalComponent  {
      animal:any;
      constructor(){
      }
      getAnimal(item){
        console.log(item);
        this.animal=item.animal;
      }

    }


@Component({
 selector: 'menu',
 template: `<div style='border:1px solid blue'>Select a animal: <br> <button 
*ngFor="let item of aAnimals" (click)="selectAnimal(item);" 
 style="display:block;">{{item.animal}}</button></div>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})

@Component({
 selector: 'footer',
 template: `<div style='border:1px solid green'><h1>THIS IS THE FOOTER </h1> </div>`,
 styles: [`div{position: absolute;bottom: 0;width: 100%;}`]
})
```

Comment: it's not issue of router outlet. what component you have loaded based on that it's setting height

Comment: @TheParam I do not understand your question. the component that is loaded in <router-outlet> is principalComponent. they are also injected but on the outside (outside of <router-outlet>): MenuComponent and FooterComponent. I would like principalComponent to say <router-outlet> have the available height between the MenuComponent and FooterComponent

Comment: I mean the component which loaded in router-outlet based on that it's height will set

Comment: @TheParam principalComponent

Answer (score 0):

I surrounded router-outlet with div.

Comment: I am not sure htis is an attempt to answer the question

Comment: can you add a working example by forking the stackblitz in the queston, that will make it a better quality answer

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it